# Regular expression with [ or ( in python

Tags: python, regex

I need to extract IP address in the form

```
prosseek.amer.corp.com [10.0.40.147]
```

or

```
prosseek.amer.corp.com (10.0.40.147)
```

with Python.  How can I get the IP for either case with Python?  I started with something like

```
site = "prosseek.amer.corp.com"
m = re.search("%s.*[\(\[](\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)" % site, r)
```

but it doesn't work.

### ADDED

```
m = re.search("%s.+(\(|\[)(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)" % site, r)
m.group(2)
m = re.search(r"%s.*[([](\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)" % site, r)
m.group(1)
```

seems to work.

Comment: You should probably literalize `site` before injecting into the pattern (e.g. those periods becomes dot metacharacters), and you can probably use `\s*` instead of `.*`.

Comment: works just fine for me. Could you elaborate please what precisely doesn't work?

Comment: I am confused about this question, you say you need to extract in the form: 'prosseek.amer.corp.com [10.0.40.147]'  but you have: 
site = "prosseek.amer.corp.com"  edit: oh you know the site, but want the IP? pretty trivial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to escape meta-characters (`*`, `(`, `)`, `.`, ...) in character groups (except `]`, unless it is the first character in the character group; `[][]+` would match a sequence of square brackets.)

Another tip when it comes to Python is to use `r'...'`-style strings. With them, backslashes has no special meaning. `r'\\'` would print `\\`, since backslash has no special meaning:

```
m = re.search(r"%s.*[([](\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)" % site, r)
```

In the above string it doesn't make any difference though, since `\d` doesn't mean anything in Python, but when it comes to stuff like `\r`, `\\`, etc., it makes lives easier.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
[([]
```

The characters inside the outer brackets are taken literally. You do not need to escape them with a backslash.

For example:

```
import re
site = "prosseek.amer.corp.com "
m = re.search("%s\s*[([](\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)" % site, 'prosseek.amer.corp.com (10.0.40.147)')
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest a few slight refinements to what you have:

```
site = "prosseek.amer.corp.com"
m = re.search(r"%s\s+[([](\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)" % re.escape(site), r)
m.group(2)
```

The changes are:

- Pass `site` through `re.escape` so that it is interpreted literally; otherwise the dots in the domain name can match any character.  This is extra important if `site` comes from user input; you don't want someone to be able to stick a regular expression in there and break your program.
- Use `\s+` instead of `.+` in between the site name and the IP address, so that it only accepts whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

```
re.findall("(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}", site)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you just ignore the brackets?

```
site = "prosseek.amer.corp.com"
m = re.search("%s.*(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)" % site, r)
```

Comment: I tried, but it gives me 0.0.40.147. The first digit of 1 is gone.

Comment: try `%s.*?(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)`

Answer (score 0):

```
import string    
site='prosseek.amer.corp.com (10.0.40.147)'
''.join([c for c in site if c not in string.ascii_letters+' []()']).strip('.')
```

For some reason I like this better than regex